# Javascript unable to read the JSON data with one field

Tags: javascript, json, vb.net, wcf

I have been in a big problem I need your help.

I am using wcf for sending XML from vb.net server to the Client side in HTML using WCF.
I am using XML data and it is converted in to JSON using serialization and at the client side I could able to read when I have only one field as shown below.

```
{"GetDataResult":"{\"?xml\":{\"@version\":\"1.0\",\"@encoding\":\"utf-8\"},\"Texts\":{\"Item\":{\"Id\":\"1\",\"Name\":\"ravi\"}}}"}
```

I am doing following way for reading data in client side

```
p = eval(d.GetDataResult);
result = json.parse(p);
alert(result.Texts.Item[0].Id);
```

But Iam getting an error Undefined.

{"GetDataResult":"{\"?xml\":{\"@version\":\"1.0\",\"@encoding\":\"utf-8\"},\"Texts\":{\"Item\":{\"Id\":\"1\",\"Name\":\"ravi\"}}}"}

But when I have more than two Items I don't have any problem.

```
{"GetDataResult":"{\"?xml\":{\"@version\":\"1.0\",\"@encoding\":\"utf-8\"},\"Texts\":{\"Item\":[{\"Id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"ravi\"},{\"Id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"raj\"}]}}"}
```

Please help me anybody in solving this issue. Would much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the square brackets.

Try the first scenario but with the square brackets like this:

`{"GetDataResult":"{\"?xml\":{\"@version\":\"1.0\",\"@encoding\":\"utf-8\"},\"Texts\":{\"Item\":[{\"Id\":\"1\",\"Name\":\"ravi\"}]}}"}`

Comment: But The data Iam  getting is directly from the server converting XML to json Using JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc)

Comment: But I tried manually by putting the Square brackets it does not work.